# Node VM - require() on first level OK, fails on second level

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to use Node's VM to dynamically load an external script that generates an object. The object is three prototypes deep (Grandparent->Parent->Child).

Everything works fine if all three prototypes are in the same file.

Everything works fine in two files, with *child.js* and *parent-grandparent.js*. I add "module" and "require" to my VM sandbox, and provide a custom requireShim and saw that it fired correctly... *child.js* correctly requested *parent-grandparent.js* and everything worked right.

However, it doesn't work when using 3 separate files. *child.js* still correctly requests *parent.js* through requestShim, but on the next level up *parent.js* ignores the provided shim and uses an internal require() for *grandparent.js* directly <strike>(and for some reason can never locate the file)</strike> (and for some reason only works if all files are in the app's root folder, refusing to handle subdirectories)

Here's my VM code. It runs an external script and expects the new object to be found in *result*.

**app.js**

```
var child = getScriptObject("./scripts/child.js")

function getScriptObject(scriptFilename)
    {
    var sandbox = { "module": module, "result": false, 
                    "require":requireShim, "console":console };

    var script = vm.createScript( fs.readFileSync(scriptFilename) );
    script.runInNewContext(sandbox);
    return sandbox.result;
    }

function requireShim (x)
    {
    console.log("requireShim: "+x);
    return require(x);
    }
```

**grandparent.js**

```
function Grandparent() {};
module.exports = Grandparent
```

**parent.js**

```
console.log("Parent requiring Grandparent...");
var Grandparent = require('./scripts/grandparent.js');

function Parent() { Grandparent.call(this); };
Parent.prototype = Object.create(Grandparent.prototype);    
Parent.prototype.constructor = Parent;

module.exports = Parent
```

**child.js**

```
console.log("Child requiring Parent...");
var Parent = require('./scripts/parent.js');

function Child() { Parent.call(this); };
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);  
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

result = new Child();
```

With the following output:

```
Child requiring Parent...
requireShim: ./scripts/parent.js
Parent requiring Grandparent...

module.js:322
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './scripts/grandparent.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:320:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:262:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:349:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\RemHaz2\zone\scripts\parent.js:2:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:444:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:462:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:339:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:294:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:349:17)
```

Note that Child->Parent worked fine, but Parent->Grandparent ignored the shim and could not handle the subdirectory for some inexplicable reason.

Comment: you should order your code [child - parent - grandparent]

Answer (score 1):

If `parent.js` is in the same directory as `child.js`, then:

```
var Parent = require('./scripts/parent.js');
```

Should be:

```
var Parent = require('../scripts/parent.js');
```

Or:

```
var Parent = require('./parent.js');
```

Likewise for:

```
var Grandparent = require('./scripts/grandparent.js');
```

Whereas `"./scripts/child.js"` from `app.js` works as `app.js` is a sibling of the `scripts` directory that is that they share the same parent directory.

Comment: Sorta figured it out. The first level (child) is run from the app.js directory, so child has to use require("./scripts/parent.js"). The second level (parent) is run from the scripts folder, so parent has to use require("./grandparent.js"). I didn't expect a directory change in the middle, since all files are in the same folder. But the biggest problem is that it's not running the shim I provided for it to use after the first level.